# Apparent weight in diurnal motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

An object of mass $m$ is on the equatorial plane. Now it is moving in a circle of radius equal to the radius of earth $R$. The object is moving with angular acceleration $\omega$. Let us observe from the reference frame of the object. Then pseudo centrifugal force $m\omega^{2}R$ will act in the opposite direction of $mg$. Now considering the normal reaction as well,we get $mg=N+m\omega^{2}R$ or $N=mg-m\omega^{2}R$. But we know $g'=g-\omega^{2}R$. Then how do we deduce $R=mg'$?Why does the normal reaction have to be mass times $g'$(what is it's identity?)?

Comment: You say "only these two forces are acting on the object".  Is it not sitting on the earths surface or otherwise supported?  Is it in orbit/freefall?

Comment: It's on the earth surface.

Comment: *The object is moving with angular **acceleration** $\omega$*. Do you not mean velocity?

Comment: *Then how do we deduce $\textbf{R} = mg'$?* Do you not mean $N = mg'$?

Answer (score 1):

Taking towards the centre of the Earth as positive and applying Newton's second law to a system which consists of just mass $m$, $F = ma \Rightarrow mg-N = mr^2\omega$ where $N$ is the normal force on the mass due to the Earth.

Again with the system being the mass but now considering the rest frame of the mass which is acceleration, applying Newton's second law $mg-N - mr^2\omega = m\,0$ where $mr^2\omega$ is the pseudoforce which is included to make the second law work in a rotating frame.  One could rewrite the equation as $m(g-r^2\omega)-N =0 \Rightarrow m g'= N$ where $g'=g-r^2\omega$ is the acceleration of the mass if the mass was allowed to fall freely and $mg'$ would be the reading on a spring balance (bathroom scales with an internal spring).

If $\omega$ increased then $N$ would get smaller until a situation when $g'=0$ and hence $N=0$ with the mass appearing to be weightless.

Comment: Thanks a lot!A question,since $N$ is directed to the opposite direction of $mg$,how can we say that $g'$ is the acceleration when the body is allowed to fall freely from that place?I mean $mg'$ is being directed radially outward,if it was being directed radially inward i would have understood.

Comment: Also could you please just deduce the $mg'$ when we are talkkng about centripetal instead of centrifugal force?In that case $m\omega^{2}R$ wouldn't be an individual force,instead it would be the resultant force working inward,i think in that case $m\omega^{2}R=mg-N$ and this is radially inward,so the body should fall freely with acceleration $\omega^{2}R$.

Comment: Please forgive me if i am being too dumb,i just wanted to clear my concepts. I hope you will keep this junior's request.

Comment: In free fall the normal force does not exist and so the force in the rest frame of the body is $m(g-r\omega^2) = mg'$ **towards the centre of the Earth**. In an inertial frame looking at the body in free fall the equation of motion is $F=ma \Rightarrow mg = mg'+mr\omega^2$ as the body is undergoing a linear acceleration $g'$ and a centripetal acceleration $r\omega^2$ towards the centre of the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

$$\omega = \frac{2\pi}{24\,{\rm h}} =\frac{\pi}{12}\,{\rm h^{-1}} $$

and you forgot the force with which the surface of the Earth pushes outward.

Comment: Do you mean the normal reaction?Supposing the normal reaction is $N$,then $N=mg-m\omega^{2}R$,but how do people write $g'=g-\omega^{2}R$?How did they deduce $R=mg'$.